# Изменение GUI в рантайме, используя css

Tags: java, css, gui, javafx

Добрый день.

В чём моя проблема: У меня есть `.fxml` файлы, в которых определена разметка. Также есть `.css` файлы, в которых я устанавливаю стили. Задача состоит в том, чтобы применить стиль, заранее описанный в `.css`, во время работы программы. Если я вызываю на объекте (допустим, на лейбле) `label.setId("someId")`, то все стили, применённые ранее сбиваются, отчего появляется много дубликата для избегания подобных вещей.

Вот небольшой кусок `.css` файла:

```
#defaultBeforeAndNowLabel {
    -fx-background-color: "C4BA62";
    -fx-text-fill: blue;
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-font-size: 1.3em;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

#changedLabelBefore {
    -fx-font-size: 1.5em;
    -fx-background-color: red;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

#changedLabelNow {
    -fx-font-size: 1.5em;
    -fx-background-color: lawngreen;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

В коде они изменяются следующим образом:

```
label.setId("changedLabelBefore");
```

Как избавиться от дублирования? Может, есть другой способ изменения отображения используя `.css`? Не хочется это всё хардкодить. Может, есть способы применения наследования?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй делать не `setId('id')`, а `getStyleClass().addAll('style1', 'style2')`. Я думаю это как раз и решит твою проблему.

**P.S.** в **css** файле надо будет писать тогда не **#changedLabelNow** а **.changedLabelNow**

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что нужно. Видел этот метод, когда искал решение, но он упорно отказывался работать, если я в fxml определял стили. Сейчас установил изменяющиеся стили через код, всё заработало.

Comment: А как можно накладывать стили поверх? Допустим, на элементе стоит стиль, в котором объявлен цвет фона, как можно добавить новый стиль, который изменяет цвет фона в соответствии с новым стилем? Сейчас я сначала удаляю старый стиль, потом добавляю новый. Есть ли другое решение?

Comment: Точно тебе не подскажу, но попробуй посмотреть тут, возможно, тут написано https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html